# How to overlay images with transparent background?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, computer-vision, python-imaging-library

Let say that I have a 2 pictures that are transparent. How can I overlay picture 1 to picture 2 so to get a result picture. Picture 1 is also smaller that picture 2. I assume that it can be done with opencv or PIL (GIMP is not allowed)

Picture number 1 :
[image: picture1]

And picture number 2 :

[[image: picture22]

That's the result that I want to get:
[image: final]

My approach : I thought that I can be done with opencv function `cv.addWeighted(src1, alpha, src2, beta, gamma[, dst[, dtype]])` what I also tried to perform.
But as the matter in fact major problems are next points:
pictures are transparent and the task is to leave pictures with higher resolution.
Rely on your answers.

Comment: [opencv does not do alpha blending yet](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/20780). you have to perform the calculations yourself... on the numpy arrays. work with entire arrays, do not touch individual pixels.

Comment: 2 steps: 1. Bring the image in the right position, which can done by warpaffine or warpperspective  2. implement your own blending or create a mask and use masked copying

Comment: @Micka. It wouldn't work that out. The second image is wider than first image. I would recommend use roi for each piece of left ear and right ear

Comment: @toyotaSupra that's why you need some kind of transformation to bring the imsges into the right shared image space. I would still recommend image warping of one or both images for that.

Comment: It wouldn't work. He desired a roi of the ear rather than the entire ear.

Comment: @toyotaSupra Obviously if you have some kind of mask or roi you want to apply you will have to apply it. But you will still need the positioning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a matter in fact, I find out the solution that suits for me. Perhaps It's not an optimal solution but at least It works.

The main idea is that I merge(paste) 2 pictures into 1 result using PIL library and the method `paste`, so that I have background and foreground.

In my case I have Picture 1 - foreground and Picture 2 - background.

My code :

```
# This function fit picture 2(background) for picture 1 . It's pare
def transform (template):
    
    img = Image.open(template)
    img_w, img_h = img.size
    image = img.resize((img_w+coef_w,img_h+coef_h),Image.ANTIALIAS)
    # change coef_w and coef_h to resize to fit template 
    image.save('updated_picture.png',"PNG")

# This function merge,compose, concat) pictures 
def compose (image, template):
    img = Image.open(image)
    img_w, img_h = img.size
    print(img.size)
    background = Image.open(template)
    print(background.size)
    # resize the image
    size = background.size
    background = background.resize(size, Image.ANTIALIAS)
    bg_w, bg_h = background.size
    offset = ((bg_w - img_w) // 2, (bg_h - img_h) // 2)
    background.paste(img, offset, mask=img)
    background.save(f'{image}_final.png', "PNG")
```

How it's work, I transform template(ears) so they would lay on the picture at center and the next one script offset foreground by center so I can get next result.
[image]

Transform is needed to make template smaller or bigger. The results would depend on of it's template. I mean the scale of ears in my case. At the next picture you can see what I mean

[image]